# What is the procedure to compile an MSI file with a barebones environment?

Tags: windows-installer

Innosetup, WiX and Visual Studio Professional users, forebear. This is not a question about these tools and their kin.

I want to produce a MSI file. I roughly know about what a MSI file is made of, by having inspected one with Orca. (shipped with the Windows 7 SDK) I know that you can make a MSI do everything and the rest. (Just because it can embed native DLL images and be made to call exported functions thereof)

I want to know how to produce a MSI file from a set of source files. In short, can anyone give me:

- The name of the compiler/assembler/packager able to produce MSI files,
- Where to find it.
- A (possibly set of) command line and a (possibly set of) minimal example source files for building a MSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment, forget the word "compile".  That is a metaphor that WiX and InstallShield brings to the table. ( .wxs -> .MSI  or .ism -> .MSI )    In a pure, barebone Windows Installer world you are simply creating MSI databases.

Technically speaking, everything you need to create a Windows Installer database is already installed on a barebones installation of Windows.  Through VB/JScript you can use the Windows Installer [Automation Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create and update databases.  For example the [Installer.OpenDatabase method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used to create an empty .MSI.  If you'd rather do this in C++ you can use the Windows Installer API [MsiOpenDatabase function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You can interop with either from a .NET application also. However, to be honest, Windows Installer XML has a library in Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) called Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller which is the gold standard for doing so.  You would not want to waste one minute of your life dealing with interop questions as they have already done this for you.

If you want to install the Windows Platform SDK  you'll find a bunch of headers and libs as well as [Windows Installer Scripting Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Then of course there is your best friend, the Windows Installer Database Editor [Orca.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Now, all of this is good foundational knowledge. But to be honest, these were just the SDK resources created by Microsoft back in 1999.  They were mainly intended for Windows Installer Tools developers not Windows Installer developers.   Which are you?   If you are creating a new tool, I thank you and hope this information helps you get started.  If you are creating MSI's,  there are much better answers I can give you outside of the limitations you set in your question.

Comment: Christopher, thank you for this demystifying answer. That is pretty much how I thought it worked. I set the limitations of the questions precisely so that someone confirms loud and clear what MSIs are about. Answer accepted.

Comment: And I want to create a MSI, so I'll use a tool instead of the API. I asked this question because I am interested in foundational knowledge. (And there are not enough simple answers on these topics)

Comment: Understanding the underlying Windows Installer techonology is very important for success with either InstallShield or WiX.  Sadly, it's a painful process to achieve this without a good mentor.  All of the information is in the Windows Installer SDK but it's a horrible, cryptic read.  I read it over and over and created/tested MSI's for 6 months before I started to feel like I understood it.  You learn by fire... read the SDK 10 times, create an MSI, have a problem in the lab, read logs files, try try again until you fix it  then go back and read the SDK and it's staring you right in the face.

Comment: Only it wasn't obvious the first 10 times you read it.  InstallShield and WiX are abstractions on top of MSI.  InstallShield provides a GUI and writes the table data.  WiX provides an XSD and XML is transformed into table data.  Both can be challenging to get working when you hit an underlying Windows Installer issue that you don't comprehend.  Both can create very good MSI's if you understand what it's doing for you and manage it.  I have a WiX based open source project (CodePlex IsWiX) that has VS project templates and UI to accelerate the authoring. I'd love to give you a free demo.